# Cron job to delete records on a certain date and time

Tags: time, cron, jobs

I have never used a cron job before so I'm looking for a little help. Basically what I need is for records to be deleted at a certain date and time that is set by the user. I have a few different tables so I don't know if I can create one script to do this for all of them or if I need to create a separate one for each table. The field that has the expiration time for the record is called *exptime*. Also, how can I set time to CST as this is the time zone that I am in.

Comment: We don't know anything about technology you use. So far, I could say that you would need one parametrized script which will be runned by some kind of scheduler (f.e CRON). That script will delete datas which fit some conditions (f.e where InsertDate > 'SomeDate'). If you would like to use CRON, you can write query which will run once at some date. It's easy to find this information in CRON tutorials but it must allows you to define   year segment. Otherwise your deletion will be performed each year unless you unregister your script from scheduler.

Comment: My date is stored in a MySQL database. My web host allows me to set up when I want the scrip to run. What I am needing help with is with writing the code in the file that will be called. I'm guessing this would be in a PHP however I'm not a coder so I really don't know where to start on this.